# How to print digits in ascending order from 1 to n using recursion ,where n is given in the parameter of that function

Tags: java, c++

My initial pseudo code looks like this

```
int ascend(int n) {
    Print number
    Return ascend
}
```

I can print from n to zero...but how do I print from zero to n using recursion?

But however I have managed to count up from zero to n numbers in ascending order.
Here is the implementation

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int countUp(int bound,int fixed) /*both parameters are passed by same 
            value whereas for every function call the 'bound' 
            variable will change and the 'fixed' variable will remain 
            as it is */
{
  int x = fixed;
  int y = bound-x;
  if(bound>2*fixed)
  {
    return 0;
  }
  else
    cout<<y<<endl;

  return countUp(bound+1,fixed);
}

int main()
{
  int var;
  cout<<"Please input the upper bound"<<endl;
  cin>>var;
  countUp(var,var);
}
```

Comment: Choose a language, write your code. Come back when you have a specific problem.

Comment: At least try something before asking.

Comment: Looks that its your homework. First tell your approach to the problem

Comment: share your approach first. community will help you refine it.

Comment: I guess the general approach to printing numbers from 1 to n would be to print the numbers from 1 to n-1 first, then put the n in last.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem At least *credit* Peano.

Comment: I'll send cheques to all his descendants.

Comment: Edited the question I have asked..:)

Comment: You're psuedo code is almost there - 1. You need to get the next value before calling ascend. 2. You need to know when to stop 3. The location of the print statement will determine if you print 0-n or n-0.

Comment: @zachary can u be more specific?

Comment: your question has tags for both java and c++, which one is correct?

Comment: @Mahmud You've put much better effort into your question with yesterday's edit. If you had done this from the start, your question would have been less likely to get closed, and you would have received much better guidance for where you're actually struggling. That said, setting `y=bound-x;` results in negative numbers. Surely you should be setting `y=fixed-bound;`?

Comment: Since your question is unlikely to get reopened, I'll offer advice in comment: You're able to count ***down*** because of the natural boundary of `0`. But you're struggling with the boundary condition when counting ***up***. Understanding the recursion stack yields a simple elegant technique to solve the problem. When you count down, you _print_ and load the stack with a smaller number on each call. E.g. `3:2:1:0` But notice how the stack in reverse is _exactly the_ same as counting ***up***. So trick is to only print as the recursive stack _unwinds_. I.e. ***after*** the recursive call.

Comment: In summary the solution for counting down is: `print(n); if (n>0) recurse(n-1);` And the **only** difference for the counting up solution is to swap the print and if statements. I.e. `if (n>0) recurse(n-1); print(n);`

Answer (score 3):

If you're a bit fuzzy on what recursion is, [this resource explains it well (in a Java context)](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/).

Let's take your psuedo code:

```
int ascend(int n) {
    Print number
    Return ascend
}
```

Currently there are a few problems with this:

1. It won't know when to stop
2. You don't call ascend with a value
3. You don't currently have a way of getting the next value in the sequence
4. You don't need to return anything

Knowing that, it is easy to fix:

(Count Up)

```
ascend(int current, int end)
    if current <= end  
        Print number;
        ascend current + 1;
```

Keep in mind that the position of your printing statement will determine whether you print ascending or descending; If it is before the recursive call, it will print in ascending order. Likewise, if it is after the recursive call it will print in descending order.

(Count Down)

```
descend(int n)
   if n >= 0
      Print n
      descend n - 1
```

Comment: Might I suggest you answer in pseudo-code rather than spoon-feeding. BTW You can achieve this more succinctly with only 1 argument; you may want to give that a try. ;) _(TIP: Your recursion termination condition should be `=0`)_

Comment: @CraigYoung Cheers for the feedback. A termination condition of =0 would assume a user doesn't feed a negative value which is an assumption I'm not willing to make ;)

Comment: Ok, go with `>0`. Worst case scenario, single print the negative (which could also have a simple condition to avoid). There's a simple elegance of stack-unwinding which I believe the exercise is intended to impart on the pupil.

Comment: but is there any chance to count up using only one parameter which should be the upper bound of the counting?

Comment: @MahmudUnNabi The location of the Print impacts whether you give the illusion of counting up or counting down. The descend method is named as such because of the implementation is start at the top and moving down - But if you moved the print statement it would have the opposite effect.

Answer (score -4):

One possible solution, using you template:

```
#include <iostream>

static int i = 0;
void ascend(int n) {
    if(i >= n) {
        i = 0;
        return;
    }
    i++;
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    ascend(n);
}

int main()
{
    ascend(20);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. Please don't spoon-feed, it encourages bad questions. 2. Your function is one-use only. Try calling `ascend()` twice.

Comment: @Craig Young : It's my fault I was sleepy and declared "i" inside the function body, however
 I think my wish to help the person asking with some actual code is not preventing him to look for additional information and better ways of doing it. Bad questions - there will be always bad questions. Nobody was born with all the knowledge. Thanks. #KeepDownVote

Comment: Your function is still one-use only. Do you understand ***why*** it's one-use only? You're not helping at all with a function that doesn't work correctly. Instead of griping about deserved down-votes (_note the plural_), try learn from them. Learn to improve your testing so you can write less buggy code. It will allow you to be a better developer in the long run.

Comment: It is legal if you reset the i variable and it keeps the original function signature.

Comment: Great! Function requirement: modify arbitrary global variable to get it working correctly. Would your sort functions require sorted input in order to work correctly?

Comment: Perhaps it can be thought as a "precondition" for using the function. It turns out though, arguing with you made me come up with a solution that does not need it and it's allowed by GCC 4.9.2.

Comment: I wasn't arguing with you, I was explaining why your answer was wrong. You've managed to fix your code, but the static var is unnecessary, and it's made your solution overly complex. You've grasped recursion but missed a subtle technique. You always make your recursive call with the same value of `n`. So you're unable to leverage information ***on the call stack***, making your "recursion" clunky. Probably the best way for me to explain at this point is to suggest you do the following and learn from it: `void ascend(int n)
{
    if (n > 0) ascend(n-1);
    std::cout << n << "\t";
}`